# TweenAnimationBuilder giving renderflex issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-renderflex-error

I wanted to make a page which shows a timer of 2 minutes and then the users can click on the button and move on to the next page. So for this I used the TweenAnimationBuilder and it works properly as long as the timer is not 0. As soon as it becomes zero it gives the following error.

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building TweenAnimationBuilder<num>(duration: 120000ms, dirty, state: _TweenAnimationBuilderState<num>#9c4a1(ticker inactive)):
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' in type cast

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  TweenAnimationBuilder<num> TweenAnimationBuilder:file:///C:/Users/Vedant/StudioProjects/activepeers_app_internship/lib/introduction/introPage.dart:60:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _IntroPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:activepeers_app_internship/introduction/introPage.dart:64:33)
#1      _TweenAnimationBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/tween_animation_builder.dart:201:26)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4806:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#6      StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#8      RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5825:32)
#9      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6375:17)
#10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#11     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#13     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#14     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#15     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#17     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#18     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#19     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#20     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#21     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#22     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#23     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#25     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5825:32)
#26     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6375:17)
#27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#28     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#29     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#30     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#31     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#32     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#33     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#34     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#35     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#36     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#37     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#38     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#39     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#40     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#42     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#43     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#44     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#45     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#46     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#47     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#48     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#49     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#50     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#51     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#52     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#53     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#54     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#55     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#56     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#57     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#58     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#59     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#60     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#61     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#62     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#63     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#64     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#65     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#66     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#67     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#68     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#69     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#70     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#71     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#72     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#73     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#74     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#75     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#76     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#77     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#78     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#79     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#80     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#81     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#82     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#83     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#84     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#85     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#86     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#87     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#88     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#89     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#90     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#91     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#92     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#93     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#94     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#95     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#96     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#97     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#98     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#99     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#100    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#101    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#102    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#103    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#104    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#105    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#106    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#107    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#108    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#109    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#110    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#111    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#112    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#113    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#114    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#115    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#116    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#117    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#118    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#119    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#120    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#121    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#122    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#123    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#124    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#125    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#126    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#127    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#128    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#129    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#130    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#131    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#132    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#133    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#134    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#135    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#136    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#137    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#138    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#139    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#140    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#141    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#142    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#143    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#144    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#145    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#146    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#147    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#148    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#149    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#150    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#151    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#152    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#153    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#154    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#155    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#156    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#157    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#158    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#159    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#160    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#161    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#162    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#163    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#164    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#165    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#166    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#167    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#168    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#169    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#170    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#171    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#172    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#173    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#174    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#175    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#176    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#177    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#178    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#179    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#180    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#181    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#182    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#183    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#184    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#185    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#186    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#187    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#188    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#189    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#190    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#191    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#192    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#193    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#194    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:108:11)
#195    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#196    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#197    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#198    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#199    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#200    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#201    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#202    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#203    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#204    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#205    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#206    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#207    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#208    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#209    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#210    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#211    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#212    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#213    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#214    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#215    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#216    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#217    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#218    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#219    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#220    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#221    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#222    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#223    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#224    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#225    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#226    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#227    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#228    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#229    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#230    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#231    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#232    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#233    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#234    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#235    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#236    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#237    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#238    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#239    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#240    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#241    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#242    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#243    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#244    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#245    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#246    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#247    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#248    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:891:21)
#249    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:370:5)
#250    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1146:15)
#251    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1083:9)
#252    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:864:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99781 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column Column:file:///C:/Users/Vedant/StudioProjects/activepeers_app_internship/lib/introduction/introPage.dart:32:16
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#5298b relayoutBoundary=up2 OVERFLOWING
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=803.6)
...  size: Size(392.7, 803.6)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
====================================================================================================
Reloaded 19 of 804 libraries in 1,051ms.
```

So since it said type 'int' in not a subset of type 'double' I changed the variables to num but still this error is coming.

This is my code-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:activepeers_app_internship/quizScreens/quiz_screen.dart';

class IntroPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const IntroPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<IntroPage> createState() => _IntroPageState();
}

class _IntroPageState extends State<IntroPage> {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body:
      Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 70,
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Image.asset("assets/logo3.png", fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            SizedBox(
              height: 70,
            ),
            Text(
              "Introduction",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Text("Take a couple minutes to\n    introduce yourselves.",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 26,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 70,
            ),
            TweenAnimationBuilder(
              tween: Tween(begin: 120.0, end: 0),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 120),
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                num val = value as double;
                num time = val;
                num min = (time/60).floor();
                num sec = (time%60).floor();
                return Text(
                  sec>=0 && sec<10?"$min:0$sec":"$min:$sec",
                  style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 80,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
                );
              },
              onEnd: () {
               print('all done');
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 70,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Color(0xff16A085),
                    padding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 20),
                    textStyle:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                onPressed: () {Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => QuizScreen()),
                );},
                child: Text(
                  "Ready now! First question please!",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                  ),
                )),


          ],
        ),
      )

    );
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there another simpler way of showing the countdown timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write this statement like this

```
Tween(begin: 120.0, end: 0.0)
```

instead of it

```
Tween(begin: 120.0, end: 0)
```

because any Tween animation accept only double value not int value so modify it then check output